# Get WordPress category description from selected category, using jquery listener to change content in p tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have it working where I can get the change to display the slug name (as its the same name as the select value), but I'm struggling to work out how to make it use that value to change out the text for the category with the same slug value.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#category-select-1').change(function(event) {
    $('#description').text($('#category-select-1').val());
  });
});
```

Any help would be amazing!

EDIT - HTML Code being used is below:

```
<section class="index blog container">
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#category-select-1').change(function(event) {
     $('#description').text($('#category-select-1').val());
});
}); 
</script>
<h2 class="maintitle"><?php echo $attributes['title']; ?></h2>
<p id="description"><?php echo $attributes['sub-title']; ?></p>
<div class="pagecontent" id="blogfilter">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="filtercontrols wp-block-columns">
<div class="post-tags wp-block-column" id="filters">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more_filters id="filterselect" target="isotope-list"]');?>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-column center centered decision" style="display:none!important;"><p>Or</p></div>
<div class="searchfield wp-block-column">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more_filters id="searchfilter" target="isotope-list"]');?>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="pagecontent blogcontent row post-listing">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more id="isotope-list" filters="true" target="filterselect" filters_url="false" filters_paging="false" filters_scroll="false" filters_analytics="false" container_type="div" css_classes="filtered-posts isotope" post_type="post" posts_per_page="9" images_loaded="true" transition_container="false" scroll="false"]'); ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I would say that i'm using a plugin to do the filtering. But its essentially just a standard drop down select thats filtering the posts below. Here is an image of what i've currently got:

[image]

But what i'm trying to do is change the description id content to be the category from the selected category. I've asked the plugin developer for help. They didn't know how to achieve it, they said to use a jQuery listener, and that was about it.

I hope this explanation helps? :)

Thanks again for reading :)

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: Have added the EDIT above :)